# IICS How Do You Orchestrate Scheduled Task Flows?

Tags: schedule, informatica, iics, orchestrate

I would like to run multiple scheduled Task Flows against the same data source but only run one at a time.

Example:
Schedule "Nightly" runs once a day (expected runtime 30 minutes),
Schedule "Hourly" runs once an hour (expected runtime 10 minutes),
Schedule "Minute" runs once a minute (expected runtime 5 seconds).

I would like:
#1 "Nightly" test status of "Hourly" and "Minute":
If they are not running, start "Nightly",
If either are running, loop around until both have stopped.

#2 "Hourly" test status of "Nightly" and "Minute":
If they are not running, start "Hourly",
If "Nightly" is running, exit,
If "Minute" is running, loop around until **both** have stopped.

#3 "Minute" test status of "Nightly" and "Hourly":
If they are not running, start "Minute",
If either are running, exit.

So far, I am using handshakes with several JSON files in the cloud.

Meaning, if "Minute" is running, the file minute.json contains information telling a caller "Minute" is running.

When "Minute" ends, it updates its file, minute.json, to reflect the operation has stopped.

As you can imagine, this is very slow.

Also, Informatica will always create a JSON file when JSON is the target.  The issue here is, if there is any issue, Informatica will create a 0 file size JSON file that will fail any operation calling it.

There has got to be a better way.

Comment: Was this answer helpful? Consider voting/accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Informatica Platform REST API v2](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources.html) to monitor and control the execution of your jobs programmatically from an external site.

It's a bit involved to set everything up and write the logic or configure driving tools but this setup should give you full control, including error handling, logging, alerting, etc.

1. [login](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources/login.html) (there are a number of options like SAML, and Salesforce credentials)
2. Then you could check the status and outcome of your jobs in the [activity log](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources/activitylog.html) or the [activity monitor](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources/activitymonitor.html) via API
3. use [job](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources/job.html) and/or [schedule](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/rest-api-reference/platform-rest-api-version-2-resources/schedule.html) via API to run your jobs.